# Data Items for queries not showing in Insertable objects view on COGNOS version 11.1.R7, how do I fix this please?

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

Our version of COGNOS Analytics was recently updated to 11.1 R7 and we now seem to have lost a function previously available to us. This was to be able to add data items to a query then when building report pages drag and drop from the available Data items rather than from Sources within the Insertable objects screen.

How do I view these in the new version, hoping my description and screenshot make sense.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screen capture of what you see under Queries please?

Comment: Can you post the report spec?

Comment: How recently was Cognos upgraded to 11.1.7?  Are you at the latest fix pack (FP6)?

Comment: Reading through your other questions, it looks like you're not getting a lot of useful answers.  It's probably because your questions are not clear and complete.  There are a lot of variables involved:  detailed Cognos Analytics version, data source type, RDBMS name and version, actual error messages, detailed input, expected output, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The data items will only appear once something is in the report.

[image]

You can't drag something from one query into another query, so it is not clear what you are asking about.[image]

Comment: Thank you for the assist, system was glitchy and after a few days the I was able to see the information as expected like your screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe Cognos got confused by a minor network blip and forgot to request the data items.  Try this.

1. Use the switcher to close the report.
2. Open the report in the editor.

If that didn't work.

1. Use the switcher to close the report.
2. Log out of Cognos.
3. Log in to Cognos.
4. Open the report in the editor.

If that didn't work.

1. Use the switcher to close the report.
2. Clear your browser cache.  (CTRL+SHIFT+DEL)  Be sure to clear cookies.
3. Log out of Cognos.
4. Log in to Cognos.
5. Open the report in the editor.

Comment: Thank you for the assist, system sorted itself out after a couple of days.